# how to make one function instead of 3 functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, routes

I noticed that the only thing that changing is the `Product.find({type:''})` in the three functions so they all the same...

can I do one function do the same work ?

routes.js file :

```
    mainRouter.get('/showChips',showChips);
    
    mainRouter.get('/showJuices',showJuices);
    
    mainRouter.get('/showSoftDrinks',showSoftDrinks);
```

controller.js file :

```
const showChips = async (req,res)=>{
    const chipsItems = await Product.find({type:'chips'});
    console.log(chipsItems);
    res.json(chipsItems)

};

const showJuices = async (req,res)=>{
    const juicesItems = await Product.find({type:'juices'});
    console.log(juicesItems);
    res.json(juicesItems)
};

const showSoftDrinks = async (req,res)=>{
    const softDrinksItems = await Product.find({type:'Soft Drinks'});
    console.log(softDrinksItems);
    res.json(softDrinksItems)
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a higher-order function that returns a function that `.find`s a particular type:

```
const makeShowProduct = type => (req, res) => {
  Product.find({ type })
    .then(result => res.json(result))
    .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget this part - don't create unhandled rejections
};
```

```
router
  .get('/showChips', makeShowProduct('chips'))
  .get('/showJuices', makeShowProduct('juices'))
  .get('/showSoftDrinks', makeShowProduct('Soft Drinks'))
```

Comment: why is that ?
handleErrors is not defined

Comment: Its implementation is up to you, but you need *something* in the `.catch` - unhandled rejections are deprecated and will cause Node to exit in new versions. Figure out what you want to do if an error is encountered, and implement that in the function.